# i cant insert temp element in the end of array rotation

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures

```
def temprotate(arr, d, n):
    temp = []
    for i in range(d):
        temp.append(arr[i])

    # Function to shift arr by 2
    for i in range(n - d):
        arr[i] = arr[i + d]

    # Function to reinsert temp elements
    for i in range(d):
        a = temp[i]
        for i in range(1, d + 1):
            arr.insert(arr[n - i], a)


def printarr(arr, size):
    for i in range(size):
        print(arr[i], end=' ')


arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
temprotate(arr, 2, 7)
printarr(arr, 7)
```

result =
3 2 4 5 6 7 6

i dont know what is wrong is the insert code section!

the insert function seems like to add elements to the list when i want it to replace elements from the list with other elements in the temp.

Comment: Edit your question to state exactly what it is you want to do, some sample input data and some output data of what you are getting vs what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you want to do but:

```
# Function to reinsert temp elements, AT THE END
    for i in range(d):
        a = temp[i]
        arr[(n-d)+i] = a

# Function to reinsert temp elements,IN SAME PLACE
    for i in range(d):
        a = temp[i]
        arr.insert(i, a)
```

Comment: sorry,my first post on stackoverflow!

Comment: your code worked thanks! my goal was to insert at the end ,can u tell me what i was doing wrong in my code!